# linker flags, categories and third party libs

Tags: ios, build, xcode4.2

I'm having some issues with building and running several libraries in an XCode project in Xcode 4.2.  Basically I'm trying to create a library (lib 1), I have a second library (lib 2) and a third party library (lib 3).

I have lib 1 with a target dependency on lib 2 and lib 3.  I then added a target dependency for the main project on lib 1.  For the time being I'm not including lib 3.

So right now lib 2 uses categories.  In order to not get the unrecognized selector error message I added `-ObjC` to lib 1's Other Linker Flags and I also added that flag to the main projects Other Linker Flags.

When I add lib 3 which requires its own set of frameworks it complains about the `-ObjC` flag.  If I remove it everything compiles fine but then I get the unrecognized selector error message.  How do I fix that?

This was one of the errors I was getting:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _dmhash in
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blah/lib.a(aes128hash.o) and 
/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blah/lib.a(aes128hash.o) for architecture armv7
```

This error only showed up while the lib 3 (third party) was being used.  It disappeared when I removed all the frameworks required by lib 3 and lib3 itself.  I then added all the frameworks one at a time compiling each time.  If I did that and added lib 3 at the end it would compile successfully as long as I left out `-ObjC` from the linker flags.  This of course resulted in me getting unrecognized selector.

Keep in mind I do not have the source for lib 3.

**Update**
Well I nuked the categories from the previous project.  That managed to get the third party lib to compile.  The problem however is that once I started making calls to that lib I'm now getting a bunch of errors.

I had to add the third party lib along with libsqlite3.0.dylib and libz.dylib to both my lib and the app to reduce it the number of errors.  I was getting 55 errors instead of 32 if I only added those libs to my own library.

Some of the errors are
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__ZNSs6assignEPKcm", referenced from:
      -[ZGXid50 processSidc:pn:nc:otp:] in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      __ZN7MtEbU23C2Ev in libSecurIDLib.a(SidcCodeGenerator.o)
      __ZN17AbstractStatement8parseRowEP12sqlite3_stmt in libSecurIDLib.a(abstractstatement.o)
      _*ZN6cSPej57LUshm17ERKSt6vectorIhSaIhEEiiRSs in libSecurIDLib.a(SidcAlgo.o)
  "*_Znwm", referenced from:
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE20_M_allocate_and_copyIPhEES3_mT_S4_ in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EEmRKh in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      -[ZGXid50 processSidc:pn:nc:otp:] in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE20_M_allocate_and_copyIPKcEEPhmT_S6_ in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      -[iueMb3 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 saveTokenToDatabase:] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      __ZN5boost6detail12shared_countC2I10TokenStoreEEPT_ in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      ...
  "__ZNSs12_M_leak_hardEv", referenced from:
      _*ZN11TokenMapper11convertDateERKN3RSA7SecurID9RtpStringIhEE in libSecurIDLib.a(tokenmapper.o)
  "*_ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE", referenced from:
      -[iueMb3 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 deleteToken:] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 removeAllTokens] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[qvFih2 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 isEulaAccepted] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 initAppData] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 setEulaAccepted:] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      ...
  "__ZSt9terminatev", referenced from:
      _*ZN3RSA6Crypto15RandomNumberGen11getInstanceEv in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenData.o)
  "*_ZdlPv", referenced from:
      __ZNSt12_Vector_baseIhSaIhEED2Ev in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE13_M_assign_auxIPhEEvT_S4_St20forward_iterator_tag in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPhS1_EEmRKh in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      -[ZGXid50 processSidc:pn:nc:otp:] in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      __ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEE13_M_assign_auxIPKcEEvT_S5_St20forward_iterator_tag in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      -[iueMb3 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 saveTokenToDatabase:] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)

Any ideas?

**Update 2**

Changed the compiler setting under build options from the default Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 to LLVM GCC 4.2 and got a different set of errors, though still getting 32 errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      -[ZGXid50 processSidc:pn:nc:otp:] in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      MtEbU23::MtEbU23()in libSecurIDLib.a(SidcCodeGenerator.o)
      AbstractStatement::parseRow(sqlite3_stmt*)       in libSecurIDLib.a(abstractstatement.o)
      cSPej5::LUshm17(std::vector > const&, int, int, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&)in libSecurIDLib.a(SidcAlgo.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      unsigned char* std::vector >::_M_allocate_and_copy(unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      std::vector >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&)in libSecurIDLib.a(SecurIDLib.o)
      -[ZGXid50 processSidc:pn:nc:otp:] in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      unsigned char* std::vector >::_M_allocate_and_copy(unsigned long, char const*, char const*)in libSecurIDLib.a(OtpProcessor.o)
      -[iueMb3 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 saveTokenToDatabase:] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count(TokenStore*)in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::_M_leak_hard()", referenced from:
      TokenMapper::convertDate(RSA::SecurID::RtpString const&)in libSecurIDLib.a(tokenmapper.o)
  "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)", referenced from:
      -[iueMb3 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 deleteToken:] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[iueMb3 removeAllTokens] in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenAdministration.o)
      -[qvFih2 init] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 isEulaAccepted] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 initAppData] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      -[qvFih2 setEulaAccepted:] in libSecurIDLib.a(AppDataManager.o)
      ...
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      RSA::Crypto::RandomNumberGen::getInstance()     in libSecurIDLib.a(TokenData.o)

Comment: What do you mean "it complains.."? What is the error/warning ?

Comment: This was one of the errors I was getting ld: duplicate symbol _dmhash in /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blah/lib.a(aes128hash.o) and /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blah/lib.a(aes128hash.o) for architecture armv7  That was just one of the errors, kept changing between not finding objc.dylib, that and some other one I don't remember which is why I removed the third library for now.

Comment: So, is one occurrence of the duplicate symbol from the third party lib that you don't have the source to?

Comment: Ok, you really need to update the question with this info, not put it in comments. So is the symbol dmhash duplicated in your liba just because of a naming coincidence or because you linked in another third party library you haven't mentioned yet?